# Predicting radius of circle with Neural Network

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network

I am generating uniformly distributed data points in a circle shape, where the radius of each circle is also generated uniformly. These circles look like this:

[image]

the uniformly distributed radia look like this:

[image]

My goal in this exercise is to predict the radius of these circles with a NN just by inputting the x,y-coordinates of the data points. (I am generating 1000 circles with its radia and data points for this)

But when trying this with the following architecture:

```
model = Sequential()

model.add(Flatten(input_shape=(X.shape[1],2)))
model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile('adam', 'mse', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()
```

I get these results:

```
model.predict(X_test)[:10]

array([[1.0524317],
       [0.9874419],
       [1.1739452],
       [1.0584671],
       [1.035887 ],
       [1.1663618],
       [1.1536952],
       [0.7245674],
       [1.0469185],
       [1.328696 ]], dtype=float32)

Y_test[:10]

array([[1.34369499],
       [0.9539995 ],
       [1.73399686],
       [1.56665937],
       [0.40627674],
       [1.73467557],
       [0.87950118],
       [1.13395495],
       [0.51870017],
       [1.28441215]])
```

[image]

as you can see the results are very bad when predicting the radius.

What am I missing here? Or is a NN just not the best way to do this task?

[EDIT]

Now I tried it with 100k circles and their corresponding radia:

[image]

The plot shows the real value against the prediction of the radius. with more training samples the prediction is much better, but for such a simple task there is still a big scatter around y = x.

Comment: Is there a way for you to post the code for creating the dataset too ? So I can try on my own computer.

Comment: are you unhappy about the training or the validation loss? How large is your training/test set?

Comment: Is the center of each circle at (0, 0)?

Comment: @Joe the center of each circle (x,y) is also created with a uniform distribution

Comment: @CAFEBABE print(X_train.shape, X_test.shape, Y_train.shape, Y_test.shape)
(800, 50, 2) (200, 50, 2) (800, 1) (200, 1)

Comment: what do you have in mind? how could I share the code? @KoralpCatalsakal

Comment: There are also other non-AI approaches, like a circle fit with three parameters (x,y of centroid and radius). Objective function is the distance of the points to that circle. Or you could transform your data to an image and use Houghs. Depends on if you are just enjoy playing with a neural network or if you really need the results :)

Comment: how can i transform my dataset into an image? maybe with this approach I also could try it out with a CNN.
it is both, I like playing with NN and also need the results :D @Joe

Comment: You already have the image and posted it above. Just set axis equal. Or you could use 2d binning in numpy, I think it's np.histogram2d and you get a 2d array that should work with Houghs in scikit image or OpenCV

Comment: Do points from multiple circles appear in the single input set? Do those circles share the same radius or radii can differ? If you have points from multiple circles of different radius you actually can have multiple answers to the same input. The network will try to estimate a mean value which can often be very incorrect

Comment: I am inputting all the circles with their radii separately; to do so I create separate boxes where each box contains one circle.
the plot of the circles is a bit confusing because actually I just plotted 3 of these boxes at once @tstanisl

Answer (score 1):

I have some suggestions, as you seem to be having Overfitting:

1. As you are in a regression task, replacing the 'accuracy' metric for 'mse' would help evaluate your situation, as 'accuracy' is more used in classification problems.
2. Not always the last epoch of your training will have the best results. That's why there are Callback functions. It is possible to check, during your training, what was the best training weights and use them in the and. Check this: https://keras.io/api/callbacks/ . I recommend, in your case, to use ModelCheckpoint to save only the best weights and EarlyStopping to stop training once your validation score isn't getting any better.
3. It's always good to check whether your model has high variance or high bias. Good ref: https://towardsdatascience.com/understanding-the-bias-variance-tradeoff-165e6942b229 In this case, you can use regularization terms to prevent a big variance in your outputs. Check this: https://keras.io/api/layers/regularizers/
   As it applies penalties to complex models, it will force a tradeoff between simplicity and effectiveness.

This is not all that it's possible to do, but I believe those points will be of great help.

Answer (score 0):

I think your results look quite fine. In the loss vs. epochs plot you see that your model is just memoizing/fingerprinting your training data. Which will happen as long as you do not increase your TD significantly.

In a classical feature engineering approach, you would normally center the training data at the average of the points. afterwards You sort the data points in decreasing `x` and `y` orientation. With this pre-processing the task will indeed be simple.

Instead you could also try the following procedure. Again sort the points along the `x` axis and `y` axis afterwards use 1-d convolutional layers as input. The hope would be that the model learns the concept of a radius.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could convert this problem to category prediction if this suits you. You could categorize dots in circles as circles and produce other random dots as augmented data, and post this as softmax or binary prediction problem.
You could use:

```
def make_circle(r,phi):
    return r*np.cos(phi), r*np.sin(phi)

phis=np.arange(0,6.28,0.01)

r = random.rand(10)
x,y = make_circle(r, phis)
```

For making the circles and than simple random dots generator for other dots.
Deep network should be able to find the circle pattern.